# Difference between a script and a program?

Tags: scripting

What is the difference between a script and a program? Most of the time I hear that a script is running, is that not a program? I am bit puzzled, can anybody elaborate on this?

Comment: Both are synonyms

Comment: My two cents (as a comment since question is closed): A program is a sequence of instructions that can be executed by some automated means -- including machine code, script, and bytecode. A script is a program written in a programming language that is interpreted by a native (machine code) application (program) and is generally written by a human. But some people consider a program to be compiled (machine code)

Answer (score 55):

For me, the main difference is that a **script is interpreted**, while a **program is executed** *(i.e. the source is first compiled, and the result of that compilation is expected)*.

Wikipedia seems to agree with me on this :

[**Script**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_%28computing%29) :

> "Scripts" are distinct from the core
>   code of the application, which is
>   usually written in a different
>   language, and are often created or at
>   least modified by the end-user. 
>   
> Scripts are often interpreted from
>   source code or bytecode, whereas the
>   applications they control are
>   traditionally compiled  to native
>   machine code.

[**Program**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_program) :

> The program has an executable form
>   that the computer can use directly to
>   execute the instructions. 
> The same
>   program in its human-readable source
>   code form, from which executable 
>   programs are derived *(e.g., compiled)*

Comment: You say, "(i.e. the source is first compiled, and the result of that compilation is expected)." Do you mean "compilation is executed"?

Comment: It seems that the definition of 'program' is a matter of opinion. Some say program is compiled to machine code; clearly a script is not that. Some say program is more general; anything that is executable; a sequence of instructions; which then includes scripts. ... Shades of gray: is java/c# a program? Compiles to intermediate language that is not machine code, but is not script (or is it?) and at least sometimes is compiled to machine code at runtime (JIT). Personally, I like program to mean a sequence of instructions. But clearly there is no consensus on that.

Answer (score 54):

I take a different view.

**A "script" is code that acts upon some system in an external or independent manner** and can be removed or disabled without disabling the system itself.

**A "program" is code that constitutes a system.** The program's code may be written in a modular manner, with good separation of concerns, but the code is fundamentally internal to, and a dependency of, the system itself.

Scripts are often interpreted, but not always. Programs are often compiled, but not always.

Comment: What is **the system** means?

Comment: @explorer - It's the system referred to in a first part of the paragraph.

Comment: :-) Okay! What is **the system** referred in the first part of the paragraph? Is it an application, operating system, an application with many integral/individual parts, or anything else?

Comment: Nevermind! I understood! I did not properly interpreted **constitutes** earlier.

Comment: My doubt is clarified! Thanks!

Comment: @explorer How did it clarified? Please do explain.

Comment: This defines both script and program in terms of 'system'. Which begs the question: What is a system?

Comment: @Asker - I thought I made the definitions mutually exclusive. "external and independent" versus "internal or dependent".

Answer (score 14):

Typically, a script is a lightweight, quickly constructed, possibly single-use tool.  It's usually interpreted, not compiled.  [Python](http://www.python.org/) and [bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash) are examples of languages used to build scripts.

A program is constructed in a compiled language, like C or C++, and usually runs more quickly than a script for that reason.  Larger tools are often written as "programs" rather than scripts - smaller tools are more easily developed as scripts, but scripts can get unwieldy as they get larger.  Application and system languages (those used to build programs/applications) have tools to make that growth easier to manage.

You can usually view a script in a text editor to see what it does.  You can't do that with an executable program - the latter's instructions have been compiled into bytecode or machine language that makes it very difficult for humans to understand, without specialized tools.

Note the number of "oftens" and "usuallys" above - the terms are nebulous, and cross over sometimes.

Answer (score 13):

See:

**[The Difference Between a Program and a Script](https://web.archive.org/web/20120209203426/http://use.perl.org/~chromatic/journal/35804)**

A Script is also a program but without an opaque layer hiding the   (source code) whereas a program is one having clothes, you can't see it's source code unless it is decompilable.

Scripts need other **programs** to execute them while programs don't need one.

Comment: This link now 404s.

Comment: This link now 200s.

Comment: **"This link" offers a much better explanation than "this answer" does.**  The purpose of compiling code is **not** to "hide" or "dress" anything... I'm surprised this answer got so many votes (and is from such a high-rep user) since it serves little purpose besides making newb's stop asking a common question, by grossly oversimplifying, and circulating puerile misinformation.

Answer (score 7):

A "program" in general, is **a sequence of instructions written so that a computer can perform certain task**.

A "script" is code written in a scripting language. A scripting language is nothing but **a type of programming language in which we can write code to control another software application**.

In fact, programming languages are of two types:

a. Scripting Language

b. Compiled Language

Please read this: 
[Scripting and Compiled Languages](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_programming_language_and_scripting_language)

Answer (score 4):

Scripts are usually interpreted (by another executable).

A program is usually a standalone compiled executable in its own right (although it might have library dependencies), consisting of machine code or byte codes (for just-in-time compiled programs)

Answer (score 3):

There are really two dimensions to the scripting vs program reality:

1. Is the language powerful enough, particularly with string operations, to compete with a macro processor like the posix shell and particularly bash? If it isn't better than bash for running some function there isn't much point in using it.
2. Is the language convenient and quickly started?  Java, Scala, JRuby, Closure and Groovy are all powerful languages, but Java requires a lot of boilerplate and the JVM they all require just takes too long to start up.

OTOH, **Perl, Python**, and **Ruby** all start up quickly and have powerful string handling (and pretty much everything-else-handling) operations, so they tend to occupy the sometimes-disparaged-but-not-easily-encroached-upon "scripting" world. It turns out they do well at running entire traditional programs as well.

Left in limbo are languages like Javascript, which aren't used for scripting but potentially could be. *Update:* since this was written [node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) was released on multiple platforms. In other news, the question was closed. "Oh well."

Answer (score 1):

According to my perspective, the main difference between script and program:

Scripts can be used with the other technologies. Example: PHP scripts, Javascripts, etc. can be used within HTML.

Programs are stand-alone chunks of code that can never be embedded into the other technologies.

If I am wrong at any place please correct me.I will admire your correction.

Comment: What about python script? 
Also, the affirmation Php code can be used with Html is wrong.
You only have php code. File extension is `.php`. Inside your program you can print html code. You can do the same with python, java, C#, C etc. All of them (if web program) produce html code.

Comment: What would be an example of program by this definition? Most people consider an exe to be a program, but it runs in an operating system. As it's embedded in that OS (a technology), it is therefore not a program?

Answer (score 1):

**script**: it contains set of "scripting language" instructions which controls, runs other system programs, applications also it can be scheduled.

**Program**: it contains set of instructions, which performs certain task upon compilation of the program with the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

A framework or other similar schema will run/interpret a script to do a task.  A program is compiled and run by a machine to do a task

Answer (score 0):

IMO
Script - is the kind of instruction that program supposed to run
Program - is kind of instruction that hardware supposed to run

Though i guess .NET/JAVA byte codes are scripts by this definition