# Difference between Scriptable and programmable

Tags: scripting, terminology

I was confused as to what is the difference between a Script and a Program, but a previously asked question [Difference between a script and a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286552/difference-between-script-and-program) clarified my doubt but that further leads me to wonder what is the difference between an Object being Scriptable versus being Programmable.

Comment: What sort of "Object"? What context are we talking about here?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but scripts are generally interpreted at runtime by another program which does something meaningful, whereas programs are typically executable directly on top of the CPU because they were compiled to assembly.

Notable exceptions are .NET managed languages and Java, which 'compile' to IL and bytecode and need some kind of runtime (CLR, JVM, DVM) to execute.

Comment: As a StackOverlflow newbie, I'm still learning the ropes.  So I can avoid giving bad answers in the future, can someone tell me why this post is subpar and therefore got downvoted?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Michael Petrotta in the question you reference, scripts are generally interpreted and slowish , programs are generally compiled and fasterish.  Compiled is often faster than intepreted because interpretation includes compilation at run time (vague and not always the case, but good enough).

Scriptable, to me, means that the object in question supports the interfaces required to be accessable from one or more script languages (for example, JavaScript and/or VBScript).

Programmable, to me, means that the object in question supports the interfaces required to be accessable from a programming language (for example, C++ or Java).

Interpreted and Compiled languages are all programming languages so it is all programming.

Summary: Scriptable vs Programmable are two vaguely synonomous terms.