# what actually is scripting language?

Tags: javascript, scripting-language

I was reading the material about the groovy language and spotted the word scripting language.At http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language, this is the statement:

> A scripting language or script language is a programming language that
>   supports the writing of scripts, programs written for a software
>   environment that automate the execution of tasks which could
>   alternatively be executed one by one by a human operator.

If I go by this statement then ever language like Java, C or JavaScript is a scripting language. Is Java also classified as scripting language?

It further says:

> Scripts can be written and executed on the fly, without explicit
>   compile and link steps; they are typically created or modified by the
>   person executing them.[1] A scripting language is usually interpreted
>   from source code or bytecode.[2] By contrast, the software environment
>   the scripts are written for is typically written in a compiled
>   language and distributed in machine code form; the user may not have
>   access to its source code, let alone be able to modify it.

On one side it is saying `the scripts are written for is typically written in a compiled language and distributed in machine code form` on the other hand it is saying Scripts can be written without explicit compile.

Could any explain in what actually scripting language and which languages fulfil this criteria?

Comment: Many such questions already exist. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286552/difference-between-script-and-program

Comment: "_the software environment_ the scripts are written for..." That's saying that the interpreter may be written in a compiled language, though the scripting language it interprets is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is a language considered a scripting language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101055/when-is-a-language-considered-a-scripting-language)