# new to C and struggling with use of *, & to reference objects

Tags: c

I am very new to C coming from deep PHP & BASH where variable variables make life easy. I am trying to understand in C how to create an object in `main()` then call a `secondFunction()` that works on this object, then on return to `main()` merge this object back into the program.

I can get the scripts to compile, but it throws a `segmentation fault` on the `main()` merge.

After reading lots of posts and tutorials I think I am mixing up when to use `myVar`, `*myVar`, `&myVar`

scriptOne.c -> main()

```
int main(){
    GstElement *myPipeline;
    GstElement *myBin;
    doAddBin(myBin);
    gst_bin_add (GST_BIN (myPipeline), myBin); // Segmentation Fault , main merge
```

scriptOne.c -> doAddBin()

```
void doAddBin(GstElement *MyBinAlpha){
    char *bin_name;
    bin_name="bin_0";
    MyBinAlpha = gst_bin_new (bin_name); <--This is where object is produced

    doWorkOnBin(MyBinAlpha);
```

ScriptTwo.c -> doWorkOnBin()

```
void doAddBin(GstElement *MyBinBeta){
    src1 = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "idFileSrc");
    gst_bin_add (MyBinBeta,src1);
    return;   // work now finished, return to main()
              // where myBin now contains src1
```

So I take I am not using the `*` correctly and need to replace it with `&` somewhere to stop the `segmentation fault`

thanks Art

Comment: Working with pointers (that is what these are called) can be very confusing. Spend some time simply learning about what a pointer is exactly. It takes college students semesters to fully grasp it, so don't feel discouraged
http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-pointer-concept/

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code? Also, you're referring to C code as "scripts", which is [incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286552/difference-between-a-script-and-a-program).

Comment: @j.seashell, thanks for the document, I was close but did not come across `**` before and this helps visualise the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, all function parameters are pass by value.  So changing the value of a function parameter is not visible outside of the function.

What you can do however is pass the **address** of a variable using the `&` operator, then inside the function you **dereference** that pointer using the `*` operator so that you're actually changing a variable in the calling function.

```
// accept the address of a pointer
void doAddBin(GstElement **MyBinAlpha){
    char *bin_name;
    bin_name="bin_0";
    // derefernce the pointer to assign to myBin in main
    *MyBinAlpha = gst_bin_new (bin_name); <--This is where object is produced

    doWorkOnBin(*MyBinAlpha);

    ScriptTwo.c -> doWorkOnBin();
}

int main(){
    GstElement *myPipeline;
    GstElement *myBin;
    // pass in the address of the pointer
    doAddBin(&myBin);
    // now myBin has been updated     
    gst_bin_add (GST_BIN (pipeline), myBin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow I was so close as I tried that combination but did not use `**`. I will have to read up on the `**` as I had not come across it before. If I am extending this concept to threading, does the logic remain the same?  many thanks for the concise answer @dbush

Comment: @artvanderlay Where `*` creates or dereferences a pointer to an object, `**` simply does the same for a pointer to a pointer to an object... As a pointer is just a variable that holds an address, then you can of course create a second variable that holds the address of a variable that holds another address, i.e. this second address now points to an address that points to an object. (Yes this can be extend some way to add a silly amount of indirection if required like `int ******p;`, but in good design it should never *be* required)